# Many mysql queries blocked in sending mode

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am using opencart and I can se many queries blocking the mysql server. All queries are the same except the p.manufacturer_id. Attached there is the query and the explain of the query. Any help on why is being blocked?

```
-- Connection Id: 7847
-- User: autohut
-- Host: localhost
-- DB: autohut_store
-- Command: Query
-- Time: 39
-- State: Sending data
SELECT 
    p.product_id,
    p.price,
    p.old_product_exchange,
    (SELECT 
            AVG(rating) AS total
        FROM
            review r1
        WHERE
            r1.product_id = p.product_id
                AND r1.status = '1'
        GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating,
    (SELECT 
            price
        FROM
            product_discount pd2 USE INDEX (ORDERBY)
        WHERE
            pd2.product_id = p.product_id
                AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1'
                AND pd2.quantity = '1'
                AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00'
                OR pd2.date_start < NOW())
                AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00'
                OR pd2.date_end > NOW()))
        ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC , pd2.price ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS discount,
    (SELECT 
            price
        FROM
            product_special ps USE INDEX (ORDERBY)
        WHERE
            ps.product_id = p.product_id
                AND ps.customer_group_id = '1'
                AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00'
                OR ps.date_start < NOW())
                AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00'
                OR ps.date_end > NOW()))
        ORDER BY ps.priority ASC , ps.price ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS special
FROM
    product p
        LEFT JOIN
    product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
WHERE
    pd.language_id = '2' AND p.status = '1'
        AND p.date_available <= NOW()
        AND EXISTS( SELECT 
            product_id
        FROM
            product_to_store p2s
        WHERE
            p.product_id = p2s.product_id
                AND p2s.store_id = '0')
        AND p.manufacturer_id = '11'
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY price != 0 DESC , price ASC , (CASE
    WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special
    WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount
    ELSE p.price
END) ASC
LIMIT 5383 , 7
```

And the explain for the query

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, PRIMARY, p, ref, PRIMARY,uc_PersonID,manufacturer_id,active, manufacturer_id, 4, const, 5387, Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1, PRIMARY, pd, eq_ref, PRIMARY,product_id, PRIMARY, 8, autohut_store.p.product_id,const, 1, Using index
2, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, r1, ref, product_id, product_id, 4, func, 1, Using where
3, SUBQUERY, , , , , , , , Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables
4, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, ps, index, , orderBy, 11, , 1, Using where
5, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, p2s, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 8, autohut_store.p.product_id,const, 1, Using index
```

There as told the same database is running on 2 VM machines on the same server. On the one where it works the same code in explain si a DEPENDENT SUBQUERY and on the machine that is not working is a SUBQUERY

This is from the server where is not working:

```
+- TEMPORARY
   table          temporary(p,pd,p2s,ps,<none>,r1)
   +- DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
      +- Filter with WHERE
      |  +- Bookmark lookup
      |     +- Table
      |     |  table          r1
      |     |  possible_keys  product_id
      |     +- Index lookup
      |        key            r1->product_id
      |        possible_keys  product_id
      |        key_len        4
      |        ref            func
      |        rows           1
      +- SUBQUERY
         +- IMPOSSIBLE
         |  warning        Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables
         +- DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
            +- Filter with WHERE
            |  +- Bookmark lookup
            |     +- Table
            |     |  table          ps
            |     +- Index scan
            |        key            ps->orderBy
            |        key_len        11
            |        rows           1
            +- DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
               +- Unique index lookup
               |  key            p2s->PRIMARY
               |  possible_keys  PRIMARY
               |  key_len        8
               |  ref            autohut_store.p.product_id,const
               |  rows           1
               +- JOIN
                  +- Unique index lookup
                  |  key            pd->PRIMARY
                  |  possible_keys  PRIMARY
                  |  key_len        8
                  |  ref            autohut_store.p.product_id,const
                  |  rows           1
                  +- Filter with WHERE
                     +- Bookmark lookup
                        +- Table
                        |  table          p
                        |  possible_keys  PRIMARY,uc_PersonID,manufacturer_id,active
                        +- Index lookup
                           key            p->manufacturer_id
                           possible_keys  PRIMARY,uc_PersonID,manufacturer_id,active
                           key_len        4
                           ref            const
                           rows           40752
```

This is from the server where is working:

```
+- TEMPORARY
   table          temporary(p,pd,p2s,ps,<none>,r1)
   +- DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
      +- Filter with WHERE
      |  +- Bookmark lookup
      |     +- Table
      |     |  table          r1
      |     |  possible_keys  product_id
      |     +- Index lookup
      |        key            r1->product_id
      |        possible_keys  product_id
      |        key_len        4
      |        ref            func
      |        rows           1
      +- DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
         +- IMPOSSIBLE
         |  warning        Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables
         +- DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
            +- Filter with WHERE
            |  +- Bookmark lookup
            |     +- Table
            |     |  table          ps
            |     +- Index scan
            |        key            ps->orderBy
            |        key_len        11
            |        rows           1
            +- DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
               +- Unique index lookup
               |  key            p2s->PRIMARY
               |  possible_keys  PRIMARY
               |  key_len        8
               |  ref            autohut_store.p.product_id,const
               |  rows           1
               +- JOIN
                  +- Filter with WHERE
                  |  +- Unique index lookup
                  |     key            pd->PRIMARY
                  |     possible_keys  PRIMARY,product_id
                  |     key_len        8
                  |     ref            autohut_store.p.product_id,const
                  |     rows           1
                  +- Filter with WHERE
                     +- Bookmark lookup
                        +- Table
                        |  table          p
                        |  possible_keys  PRIMARY,uc_PersonID,manufacturer_id,active
                        +- Index lookup
                           key            p->manufacturer_id
                           possible_keys  PRIMARY,uc_PersonID,manufacturer_id,active
                           key_len        4
                           ref            const
                           rows           40752
```

Comment: what do you mean by being *blocked* ?

Comment: what do you mean by blocked? mysql doesn't have a firewall. its either the query has an error or it was never submitted. to debug, you should take the entire query and paste it into the sql dialog to see if there's an error. is the query taking too long? is that the issue?

Comment: Yes the query is running forever without any errors. I have many queries like this in the process list and at some point mysql is crashing.

Comment: This is the most used query in OpenCart (listing products) and I do not see any reason why it should cause MySQL crashing. I have seen, run and written much more complicated and complex and resources eating queries that run without problems (though may be slower). The only problem here may be not enough of server resources (i.e. operating memory, file system memory, slow HDD, weak CPU, or all together). Try to allow MySQL to allocate more memory or more CPU threads...

Comment: The strange part is that the same database on the development server is running without problems. Both are VM on the same server same resources. I did a complete drop of the database and restore it. No change the same query running on developer server is not running on production. The system is having 16 Gb ram and 8 cores.